# How to terminate application after 10 runs?

Tags: java

I am trying to make the application stop running after you enter `0` 10 times. I'm in programming class and am very bad at it. Any help is appreciated :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Areyouboredyet
{

  public static void main (String[] args ) 
  {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int value;             

    System.out.println( "Are you bored yet? 1 for yes; 0 for no." );
    value = input.nextInt();

    while ( value != 1 )    
    {
      System.out.print("Are you bored yet? 1 for yes, 0 for no.");
      value = input.nextInt(); 
    }

    System.out.println( "Finally!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Hint: count how many times `value` is 0 , if it reaches 10 then exit the loop

Comment: Remember to accept whichever answer helped the most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  int count = 0;
  System.out.println( "Are you bored yet? 1 for yes; 0 for no." );
    value = input.nextInt();

  while ( value != 1 && count < 10)    

  {
    count = count + 1;
    System.out.print("Are you bored yet? 1 for yes, 0 for no."); value = input.nextInt(); 

  }

  System.out.println( "Finally!");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a separate counter that counts how many times you have asked your question and increment it every time you ask it. Add this variable to your while condition (eg `while(value != 1 && timesAsked < 10)`) and it will terminate your loop once the variable is more than 10.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways that you could do this, but they basically boil down to the same thing: Keep track of how many times it's been asked.

My favorite way to do that would be like this:

```
... //Initializing variables and objects and whatnot
for (int times = 0; times < 10 && value != -1; times++) {
  ... //Your code inside, which presumably changes 'value'.
}
... //Whatever comes after
```

What this does is automatically keep track of, increment, etc. a variable called `times` which records how many times you've gone through the loop. When either that reaches 10 or `value` isn't -1, it breaks out of the loop and continues. The body should be the same as you have in your `while` loop.